# Why render a scalloped pattern in dx11 when i use pcf

Tags: c++, directx-11

[image]

I add to pcf code to frank luna 3D programming example code in my shader.

But When mesh dosen't setting a normal map. The scalloped pattern rendered.

Any solution is here ?

```
vLightProj.xyz /= vLightProj.w;

float percentLit = 0.0f;

float2 vDepthMapUV = float2((vLightProj.x / 2.f) + 0.5f, -(vLightProj.y / 2.f) + 0.5f);

// Texel size.
const float dx = SMAP_DX;

const float2 offsets[9] =
{
    float2(-dx,  -dx), float2(0.0f,  -dx), float2(dx,  -dx),
    float2(-dx, 0.0f), float2(0.0f, 0.0f), float2(dx, 0.0f),
    float2(-dx,  +dx), float2(0.0f,  +dx), float2(dx,  +dx)
};

[unroll]
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
    percentLit += DepthMap.SampleCmpLevelZero(g_sam_3,
        vDepthMapUV.xy + offsets[i], vLightProj.z).r;
}
//그림자에 가려진 정도
percentLit /= 9.f;

float SpecCoef = g_tex_2.Sample(g_sam_1, vUV).x;
float4 vSpec = decode(SpecCoef);

output.vDiffuse = lightcolor.vDiff * percentLit + lightcolor.vAmb;
```